# How to do good Keyword Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I tried the sketch engine (no ad!) and I wonder what might be the underlying algorithms to do such a good keyword extraction. I have a document consitsing of rows of sentences and from each I want the proper NERs or keywords. I tried a lot. I need them to write my own NER based on CRF.

Is this just statistics used to extract the keywords or what else do you need for that? I ask in general and not how they did it, but it would be nice to find out if someone knows...